# Meaning of & in parameters

Tags: ruby, block

I saw this code for a method same as `each`, except it receives a block to run some test against every item:

```
  def every?(&predicate)
    predicate = lambda { |item| item } if predicate.nil?
    each do |item|
      return false if !predicate.call(item)
    end
    true
  end
```

Why is there a `&` in the parameter, and what does it do? What are the uses of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes in parameter lists you'll see something like

```
def foo(&block)
  logic_with block
end
```

This just means that argument is expecting a block - and in your example.

`&predicate` just means passing a block as a parameter, which we're assigning to a local variable `predicate`

You can get a good idea of this from the fact that if predicate is nil the first line of the method assigns a new lamda to the predicate variable.

For further reading here's a good posts on blocks, procs and lambdas: http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/

EDITED per sawa's explanation below.

My take was you wanted the simple explanation that if you see & in this context it means a block is expected.

If you want to know specifically what the `&` operator itself actually does there's a good blog post here: http://ablogaboutcode.com/2012/01/04/the-ampersand-operator-in-ruby/

As sawa mentions it's very similar to calling `to_proc` on the incoming block.  From the post I linked to, in more detail:

- if object is a block, it converts the block into a simple proc.
- if object is a Proc, it converts the object into a block while preserving the lambda? status of the object.
- if object is not a Proc, it first calls #to_proc on the object and then converts it into a block.

Answer (score 3):

The two operators `*` and `&` swap Ruby objects and non-objects.

- The operator `*` prepended to a list of comma-separated objects (which is not an object) converts it into an array (which is an object).

  ```
  *("foo", "bar", "baz") # => ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
  ```
- The operator `*` prepended to an object converts it into an array by applying `to_a`, and then into a list of comma-separated objects.

  ```
  *["foo", "bar", "baz"] # => ("foo", "bar", "baz")
  *nil                   # => *[] # => ()
  ```
- The operator `&` prepended to a block (which is not an object) converts it into a proc (which is an object).

  ```
  &{|e| puts e}          # => ->(e){puts e}
  ```
- The operator `&` prepended to an object converts it into a proc by applying `to_proc`, and then into a block.

  ```
  &->(e){puts e}         # => {|e| puts e}
  &:foo                  # => &->(e){e.foo} # => {|e| e.foo}
  ```

When you have a `&` in an argument position, the `&` is appended to a block, so the third case above applies. The block becomes a proc.

Comment: Right - this is a correct technical explanation of the operators. I was trying to give a pragmatic answer to what the questioner was, in my opinion, trying to understand - which is that the indication you get from a method set of parameters like that is that a block is expected. I think that's what the questioner was looking to understand. I upvoted your answer to reflect that, but I think the simpler version is the aim here.

Comment: @RichardJordan Thanks for the vote. It is okay to say that `&` expects  a block in an argument position, or to leave out some details, but it is not okay to say that a block is (just) a proc.

Comment: Yes I do know that, you are correct - that was lazy language and corrected :-)

Comment: You caused me to go down the rabbit hole and read up a lot more on this after being sloppy and I've definitely learned some stuff.

Comment: @RichardJordan Good to hear that.

Comment: +1.. really well written answer.. I liked it too much.

Answer (score 2):

In the context of a method definition, putting an ampersand in front of the last parameter indicates that a method may take a block and gives us a name to refer to this block within the method body.

I often refer to [this post](http://www.skorks.com/2013/04/ruby-ampersand-parameter-demystified/) when I get confused.